# Managed package upgrade fails as Named Credential seems to have modified

Tags: managed-package, isv, namedcredentials

But the Named Credential hasn't changed between current and new version. So this Known Issue doesn't apply: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000mCFtQAM&title=cannot-modify-managed-component-attempting-to-upgrade-managed-package-containing-named-credentials

Did there anything change with Spring'19 that could create this problem?

Note: I also created Support Case 22042201 for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved. Not the Named Credential in the package had changed between version. But the customer had populated the Credential field (empty in the package) in his org.

I think a package provider should be able to lock/protect such fields.

[image]